# Passing eval through JavaScript function not quite working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

ive got some answers from the search but my function is still not running

my code

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick='<%# "search(" + Eval("Name") + ");" %>'><%# Eval("Name") %></a></li>
```

function

```
    function search(val) {
        alert(val);
        searchPagingTable(val, '#tblUsers');
    }
```

the html looks like

```
<a onclick="search(Fred);" href="javascript:;">
```

console error

```
SCRIPT5009: 'Fred' is undefined
```

i think i need to get the quotes around the string, but if i put single quotes in the aspx, that fails too with a different error

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like so:

```
onclick='<%# "search(\"" + Eval("Name") + "\");" %>'>
```

adding the escaped quotes will fix it.

Comment: But when I tried this I got something like this func(&quot;VALUE&quot;). Any Ideas?

Comment: something is parsing the quotes. I would need more info to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the quotes around the string.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick='<%# "search(\'" + Eval("Name") + ");"\' %>'><%# Eval("Name") %></a></li>
```

By the looks of things, you were trying to call the 'search' function with a variable called 'Fred' as the argument, whereas you want to provide a string with the content set to 'Fred' as the argument. Correct me if I'm wrong.